# Edit Model Upon Leaving Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwplayer

I have a website where users can view an exercise video through embedded JW Player. I would like to add the amount of time they spent watching the video to their user model. I already have the database setup, but I don't know how to add the time watched to their user model.

For instance, if a user watches 3 minutes of the video, I want to be able to store that with in the user model. How can I call a method upon leaving the page, so I can add the amount of time they watched the video to their user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax update for that. However, you don't want to trigger this update upon leaving page because it's not reliable(Not sure if turning off `async` will do any good). Instead, you should poll your ajax update periodically(says every 10s) to update the record. Below is my suggested solution.

**VideosController**:

```
def show
  video = Video.find(params[:id])
  # Assuming Video belongs_to User, User has two fields called started_watching_at and duration 
  video.user.update_attribute(:started_watching_at, [current_time])
  video.user.update_attribute(:watching_duration, 0)
end

# This method is to update user watching time
def touch_duration
  video = Video.find(params[:id])
  # Calculate time different then convert to duration
  duration = [current_time] - [started_watching_at]
  video.user.update_attribute(:watching_duration, duration)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render nothing: true }
  end
end
```

In your js file, you basically want to poll update user record using `touch_duration` method. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  var time_to_check = 10000;
  setInterval(time_to_check, touch_duration);

  function touch_duration() {
    // Update user
    $.ajax({
      url: // update url,
      method: "PUT"
    }, function(data) {
      console.log("Successfully update!");
    });
  }
})
```

UPDATED: I forgot to mention that you may want to run the ajax update within the video show page only. I guess you can work that out easily.

Hope that answers your question. Cheers!

Comment: This looks really good. Would this cause time watched to continue to be added even if the video is paused?

Answer (score 0):

I second what @kasperite said. Another thing you can do to get a finer control over the position is use localStorage to store the position.